# How can I defeat Majordomo Executus?

Tags: hearthstone

The first two wings of Molten Core were really easy, but the third one, Ragnaros the Firelord/Majordomo Executus is giving me a bit of trouble.

The following is a typical result after bringing down the health of the Majordomo:

[image]

The two Molten Giants a regular player can use are bad enough, but four are just far too much. I can't really fit that much removal into my decks, never mind drawing it early enough.

I also need to do 46 damage in total, 30 for the Majordomo and 16 for Ragnaros. Doing that much damage with a few molten giants on the other side seems very hard if not impossible.

What is the trick to this one? How can I defeat the Majordomo and Ragnaros?

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple tricks you can use to make life a little easier against the majordomo and his master.

1: Perhaps most importantly, keep your damage back. If he's above 20 HP, he can't summon Giants, if he's at 16+, he can only summon one per turn. Build a board and/or hand full of burst.
1a: Alternatively, play Warrior, get him low, empty his hand of giants, and Brawl.

2: Abuse his 1/3 summons. Grim Patron is especially good at this, Frothing Berserker, Acolyte of Pain, and Enrage cards are also strong.

3: If you can burst him into Ragnaros form, you should probably do it. 8 damage to a random target usually isn't that bad, and once he turns into Ragnaros he can't cast Molten Giants, which are his scariest creatures. (This tactic may backfire if your board is only a couple strong creatures)

4: Don't use Hunter, you probably CAN make it work, but 2 damage to face hero power, and very limited removal don't help in this fight. You'll be better off with any other class.

Comment: Raging Worgen warrior deck would be a good choice here...

Comment: @blgt I said you probably could do it, but the hunter class has the least effective tools for the job. Hunter has less burst potential than pretty much any other class, and fewer control options as well. Hunter's strength is applying pressure through sustained damage over turns, which is what molten giants into a sudden 16 health gain counters best. Even with this being the case, I probably wouldn't have mentioned it if the Asker hadn't provided an image involving losing with hunter.

Comment: Pretty much this. I believe I used my normal laddering priest deck. I controlled the board and left him at greater than 20 life. I traded when I had to and passed otherwise. When I had +20 damage on the board I burst him to Rag phase. On his next turn he basically played a full board of giants but that didn't matter as I already had +20 damage for his 16hp/armor.

Answer (score 2):

Note what the gimmick of a molten giant is. Its mana cost lowers for **the amount of damage the hero has taken**.

So, for Majordomo Executus (ME) at 30 health, it'd cost 20 mana.
With ME at 20 health, it'd cost 10 mana.
With ME at 10 health or below, it'd cost 0 mana.

The lower ME's health is, the more giants he can play.

Now here's another trick: Ragnaros only has 8 health. Which means he can take a MAXIMUM of 7 damage (ignoring armor, since molten giant text also ignores armor). That means that for Ragnaros, molten giants AT LEAST cost 13 mana (impossible to play).

My strategy was as follows:

- Keep Majordomo Executus above 20 health, but make sure you dominate the board. Keep building the board, until you have enough damage to kill him (I'm assuming here that the minions you use for that are still alive when Ragnaros enters the game). This way, both ME and RAG never managed to play a molten giant.
- Once RAG hits the board, just make sure you haven't put all your eggs in one basket (more appropriately, all attack on one minion). Rag might kill one every turn with his hero power, but only one per turn. You can still use the others to beat his face until he dies.

The trick here is to not dramtically wound Majordomo Executus until you have enough board advantage to steamroll both him and Rag.

Answer (score 1):

To beat the heroic one i used a spinoff of the Shaman hyper death combo dek with baron rivendare, ancestral, reincrnate,sylvanas, and kt. U wait until you build a big kt sylvanas board then drop his moltens, and then take them all and kill him. The kts render rags hero power irrelevant. Worked first try.

Answer (score 1):

I won with this deck. Of course, you can change it a little bit.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Build a board, get big minions, use KT and you can trade a giant per turn. Another one is to use shadowflame with a 8+ attack minion

Answer (score 0):

The easiest win against him was a Mill Rogue deck. I brought him down to no cards while still Majordomo. Once he is at 0 cards, the damage done through fatigue gets ridiculous quick. Just save your Coldlights, or use Gang up to make sure you have a few extra and throw them out. He never got to play a Molten Giant against me, and without those Giants, he is easy to beat. Don't got at the face at all until he is out of cards, save your creatures and spells for creature removal.

Answer (score -4):

Freeze mage did the trick for me.

Comment: This is not a very well detailed answer to the question asked.